# Connecting storage securely to Azure Data Lake Analytics or Data Factory

Tags: azure-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I am setting up a new Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA) PAAS service to run USQL against some existing data sets in blob storage. The blob storage is firewalled for security and when I try to add the storage account to the data sources in ADLA I get the following error. Similar happens for data factory.

> InvalidArgument: The Storage account '' or its accessKey
>   is invalid.

If I disable the firewall, the storage account can be successfully added. I have tried to add the relevant [Azure Data Center IP Address ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=41653) but the connection still fails. I have also ticked the "Allow trusted Microsoft Services box" but this [does not seem include data lake or data factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#exceptions). How do I access my storage account from ADLA but still have it secured?

Answer (score 1):

You could install a [selfhosted IR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) to access your blob storage. Whitelist the IP of the machine hosting your selfhosted IR.

Comment: That is definitely and option but I don't want to pick up the cost and the overhead of managing a VM.